# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a una variable en angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

¿Cómo puedo acceder al `res.groupId` desde otro `suscribe`?

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.userId = (params.id) ? params.id : null
  if(this.userId){
    this._userService.view(this.userId).subscribe(res => {
      let users = <User[]>res;
      this.registerForm.controls['client'].setValue(res.clientName);
      this.registerForm.controls['em'].setValue(res.email);
      this.registerForm.controls['pass'].setValue(res.password);
      this.registerForm.controls['ph'].setValue(res.phone);
      this.registerForm.controls['groupId'].setValue(res.groupId);
    });
  }
});

this._operatorgroups.index().subscribe(res => {
  let operatorGroups = <OperatorGroups[]>res;
  this.operatorGroups  = operatorGroups;
  if(this.userId) this.registerForm.controls['groupId'].setValue(res[res.groupId].id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a valores desde un subscribe diferente es necesario que declares una variable global (o del método) y uses esta:

```
let groupId; 
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.userId = (params.id) ? params.id : null
  if(this.userId){
    this._userService.view(this.userId).subscribe(res => {
      let users = <User[]>res;
      this.registerForm.controls['client'].setValue(res.clientName);
      this.registerForm.controls['em'].setValue(res.email);
      this.registerForm.controls['pass'].setValue(res.password);
      this.registerForm.controls['ph'].setValue(res.phone);
      this.registerForm.controls['groupId'].setValue(res.groupId);
      groupId = res.groupId;
    });
  }
});

this._operatorgroups.index().subscribe(res => {
  let operatorGroups = <OperatorGroups[]>res;
  this.operatorGroups  = operatorGroups;
  if(this.userId) this.registerForm.controls['groupId'].setValue(res[groupId].id);
});
```